# WPF - Menu shows correctly but can't click it... (C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface

I've got an issue with my menu in WPF. The thing is that I use an expander an then a menu inside. When I then want to add subitems for this menuitem I just created it work fine and it show up correctly in the preview before I run the application. But when I do run the application I can't click the menu to access the subitems for that one. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my wpf code(using c#):

```
<Expander Header="Handle"
          FontSize="15"
          BorderBrush="Black"
          Margin="3,0,2,1">
  <Menu Background="White">
    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
      <MenuItem x:Name="MenuArticle"
                Header="Article"
                Height="25" 
                FontSize="13"
                Width="177"
                Click="MenuArticle_Click">
      <MenuItem x:Name="menuNewArticle"
                Header="New article"
                Height="25"
                FontSize="13"
                Width="187"/>
      <MenuItem x:Name="menuHandleArticle"
                Header="Handle article"
                Height="25"
                FontSize="13"
                Width="187"/>
    </VirtualizingStackPanel>
  </Menu>
</Expander>
```

I want it to look like this, EVEN when I run the application

[image]

Comment: `VirtualizingStackPanel` is what you are doing wrong. Ever thought about *commenting* code out and test again ? It's common thing to do when you are facing an issue.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use a `StackPanel`, just add applicable items into the `Menu's` `Items` property

```
<Expander Header="Handle" FontSize="15" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="3,0,2,1">
    <Menu Background="White">
        <Menu.Items>
            <MenuItem x:Name="MenuArticle" Header="Article" Height="25" FontSize="13" Width="177">
                <MenuItem.Items>
                    <MenuItem x:Name="menuNewArticle" Header="New article" Height="25" FontSize="13" Width="187" />
                    <MenuItem x:Name="menuHandleArticle" Header="Handle article" Height="25" FontSize="13" Width="187"/>
                </MenuItem.Items>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu.Items>   
    </Menu>
</Expander>
```

Edit:
If you want to set the placement of the menu items, see this:

[How do get menu to open to the left in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010962/how-do-get-menu-to-open-to-the-left-in-wpf)

You'll need to modify the popup placement.

Comment: Hi, this work but the result is like before, it opens verticaly instead of horizontal. Is there any commando to make the opening work with horizontal instead of vertical? Any kind of orientation?

Comment: @Huezzer you can go ahead and set the direction using an attached property. see my updated answer