# Menu items keep appearing on the left, rather than the right. How can I fix this?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, menu, menuitem

Here is a screenshot of the monstrosity.
[image]

As far as I know, the default for menu items are to appear on the right side, however, none of mine has, and I cannot figure out why.

```xml
<!-- Menu Bar -->
<DockPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5">
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <!-- File -->
        <MenuItem Header="_File">
            <MenuItem Header="_Open"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Save"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Close" Click="MenuItem_File_Exit_Click"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <!-- Settings -->
        <MenuItem Header="_Settings">
            <MenuItem Header="DQ Reasons Profiles...">
                <MenuItem Header="Import DQ Reasons Profiles" Click="DQReasonsProfileEditor_Open"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Configure DQ Reasons Profiles" Click="DQReasonsProfileEditor_Open"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
        <!-- Debug options -->
        <MenuItem Header="Add Test Data" Click="TestData_Add"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Test Sort" Click="SortCompetition"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Test Statistics" Click="TestGraph"/>
    </Menu>
    <StackPanel/>
</DockPanel>
```

If someone can explain why this annoyance is happening so I can fix it, that would be awesome!

Comment: Does this happen only in your application, or also in others, like Visual Studio? See perhaps this: https://superuser.com/questions/377897/how-to-fix-left-aligned-menu-in-visual-studio-2010

Comment: If the menu does not have enough room to fully open at the border of the window or display screen, it will compensate and open from the opposite direction of the border instead. This will override whatever side you have the menu set to open on below. Follow this link to give you more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630954/wpf-menu-displays-to-the-left-of-the-window

Comment: And this https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/786-menus-open-left-right-side.html (same instructions as @Clemens mentioned)

Comment: I don't think any of these solutions help since they only effect my end, and not the end of the user. It only happens in WPF applications, it seems. I have found some code alike one of the ones presented here that seems to fix the problem, but it's really a dummy fix. It's insane to think you can't set this left/rightness in the xaml

Comment: Well, you can. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1011313/1136211

Comment: @Clemens Oh! I see! I found all the other pages linked on my own, but this one I missed. I am not sure I follow along with it entirely, as it is a bit more advanced than my current experience, but it seems like something new to learn! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Clemens Actually, do you have any information as to how I am supposed to use the first paragraph of code provided? If you can any tips on things to look up to learn, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's all in the answer. Put the attached property declaration in a class, of course. Perhaps first read [Attached Properties Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/attached-properties-overview).